# I get "Unexpected token u" while using JitsiMeetExternalAPI

Tags: javascript, iframe, jitsi

I'm using the [External Jitsi API](https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js) by following this [example](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/api.md).
The problem is that I get a "Unexpected token u" error.

What I see is that the Jitsi External API creates an iframe with a supposed chat room URL. The problem is that the iframe url has a "external" hash appended. I tried removing the hash from the src and seems to work fine but I'm still confused.

Someone knows why the hash is needed and if it's possible to find a better way to solve that instead of editing the External Jitsi API src?

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rmuy19bk/)

```
 var domain = "meet.jit.si";
 var room = "TestRoom";
 var width = 700;
 var height = 700;
 var htmlElement = document.getElementById("jitsiRoom")
 var api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, room, width, height, htmlElement);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted with the developers by using the mailing list and I got this answer.

> Hello,
>
> It seems like issue in the Jitsi Meet code. We need the "external" hash parameter and I don't think this is the best way to solve the issue.
>
> I'll investigate it and fix it.
>
> Thank you for the report!

Seems to be a bug.

Not tested but they pushed a fix for that bug.

commit: ca5a1001a1861f1f6506d091451723ff7ebd0717